How to skip svg sprites cache for web development
my icon.svg sprite file look like this


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0" style="display:none">

    <symbol fill="currentcolor" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" id="icon_home">
        <path d="M240-200h133.85v-201.54q0-15.36 10.39-25.76 10.4-10.39 25.76-10.39h140q15.36 0 25.76 10.39 10.39 10.4 10.39 25.76V-200H720v-353.85q0-3.07-1.35-5.57-1.34-2.5-3.65-4.43L487.31-735q-3.08-2.69-7.31-2.69-4.23 0-7.31 2.69L245-563.85q-2.31 1.93-3.65 4.43-1.35 2.5-1.35 5.57V-200Zm-60 0v-353.85q0-17.17 7.68-32.53 7.69-15.37 21.24-25.31l227.7-171.54q18.95-14.46 43.32-14.46t43.44 14.46l227.7 171.54q13.55 9.94 21.24 25.31 7.68 15.36 7.68 32.53V-200q0 24.54-17.73 42.27Q744.54-140 720-140H562.31q-15.37 0-25.76-10.4-10.4-10.39-10.4-25.76v-201.53h-92.3v201.53q0 15.37-10.4 25.76-10.39 10.4-25.76 10.4H240q-24.54 0-42.27-17.73Q180-175.46 180-200Zm300-269.23Z"></path>
    </symbol>

    <symbol fill="currentcolor" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" id="icon_dashboard">
        <path d="M676.15-180q-15.36 0-25.76-10.4Q640-200.79 640-216.16V-380q0-15.36 10.39-25.76 10.4-10.39 25.76-10.39h67.69q15.37 0 25.76 10.39Q780-395.36 780-380v163.84q0 15.37-10.4 25.76-10.39 10.4-25.76 10.4h-67.69Zm-230 0q-15.36 0-25.76-10.4Q410-200.79 410-216.16v-527.68q0-15.37 10.39-25.76 10.4-10.4 25.76-10.4h67.7q15.36 0 25.76 10.4Q550-759.21 550-743.84v527.68q0 15.37-10.39 25.76-10.4 10.4-25.76 10.4h-67.7Zm-229.99 0q-15.37 0-25.76-10.4-10.4-10.39-10.4-25.76v-331.35q0-15.64 10.4-25.99 10.39-10.34 25.76-10.34h67.69q15.36 0 25.76 10.39Q320-563.06 320-547.69v331.35q0 15.65-10.39 25.99Q299.21-180 283.85-180h-67.69Z"></path>
    </symbol>
    <symbol fill="currentcolor" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" id="icon_shopping_bag">
        <path d="M252.31-100Q222-100 201-121q-21-21-21-51.31v-455.38Q180-658 201-679q21-21 51.31-21H330v-10q0-62.15 43.92-106.08Q417.85-860 480-860t106.08 43.92Q630-772.15 630-710v10h77.69Q738-700 759-679q21 21 21 51.31v455.38Q780-142 759-121q-21 21-51.31 21H252.31Zm0-60h455.38q4.62 0 8.46-3.85 3.85-3.84 3.85-8.46v-455.38q0-4.62-3.85-8.46-3.84-3.85-8.46-3.85H630v90q0 12.77-8.62 21.38Q612.77-520 600-520t-21.38-8.62Q570-537.23 570-550v-90H390v90q0 12.77-8.62 21.38Q372.77-520 360-520t-21.38-8.62Q330-537.23 330-550v-90h-77.69q-4.62 0-8.46 3.85-3.85 3.84-3.85 8.46v455.38q0 4.62 3.85 8.46 3.84 3.85 8.46 3.85ZM390-700h180v-10q0-37.61-26.19-63.81Q517.62-800 480-800q-37.62 0-63.81 26.19Q390-747.61 390-710v10ZM240-160v-480 480Z"></path>
    </symbol>
    <symbol fill="currentcolor" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" id="icon_products">
        <path d="M480-421.77q-8.85 0-17.19-2.31-8.35-2.31-16.58-6.54L119.77-604.23q-9.85-5.62-14.15-13.85-4.31-8.23-4.31-18.07 0-9.85 4.31-18.08 4.3-8.23 14.15-13.85l326.46-173.61q8.23-4.23 16.58-6.54 8.34-2.31 17.19-2.31 8.85 0 17.19 2.31 8.35 2.31 16.58 6.54l326.84 173.61q9.85 5.62 14.16 13.85 4.31 8.23 4.31 18.08 0 9.84-4.31 18.07t-14.16 13.85L513.77-430.62q-8.23 4.23-16.58 6.54-8.34 2.31-17.19 2.31Zm0-58.84 294.92-155.54L480-791.69 185.46-636.15 480-480.61Zm.38-155.54ZM480-324.46l320.15-169.46q2.39-1.39 16.31-2.69 12 .76 19.65 9 7.66 8.23 7.66 20.23 0 8.3-3.66 14.99-3.65 6.7-11.96 11.16L513.77-274.46q-8.23 4.23-16.58 6.54-8.34 2.3-17.19 2.3-8.85 0-17.19-2.3-8.35-2.31-16.58-6.54l-314-166.77q-8.31-4.46-12.15-11.16-3.85-6.69-3.85-14.99 0-12 7.85-20.23 7.84-8.24 19.84-9 4.23-.77 8.16-.04 3.92.73 8.15 2.73L480-324.46Zm0 156.15 320.15-169.46q2.39-1.38 16.31-2.69 12 .77 19.65 9 7.66 8.23 7.66 20.23 0 8.31-3.66 15-3.65 6.69-11.96 11.15L513.77-118.31q-8.23 4.23-16.58 6.54-8.34 2.31-17.19 2.31-8.85 0-17.19-2.31-8.35-2.31-16.58-6.54l-314-166.77q-8.31-4.46-12.15-11.15-3.85-6.69-3.85-15 0-12 7.85-20.23 7.84-8.23 19.84-9 4.23-.77 8.16-.04 3.92.73 8.15 2.73L480-168.31Z"></path>
    </symbol>
</svg>



and show icons using use tag


<ul>
  <li><svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="view/image/icon.svg#icon_home"></use></svg></li>
  <li><svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="view/image/icon.svg#icon_dashboard"></use></svg></li>
</ul>



it work fine when i add a new symbol, but it's not showing new icon if i update an existing symbol path tag to a new icon. it still loads the old icon. seems like a cache problem because it work fine when i try in incognito mode. Hard refresh is not working too. please help suggesting a better way to skip svg sprites cache for web development.

You may try to add a dynamic query param to your url like view/image/icon.svg?v=20130205#icon_home e.g based on a timestamp. You can also disable all caching in dev tools . Provided you leave them opened - you should always see a new version. If you're still frequently changing icons you may also opt for an inline SVG asset and change the references to an external file once you'r finished the icon design work.

i think your suggestion of using dynamic query parameter would work just fine. to further improve it, i will create a common function to print icons with query parameter for development, then later remove query parameter from that function on live site.
However still looking for more seamless solution.

i think the best solution till now is:
create an icon.svg file and put your icons in it. give every icon a distinct id. i am using a icon_ prefix. for example


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0" style="display:none">

    <symbol fill="currentcolor" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" id="icon_home">
        <path d="M240-200h133.85v-201.54q0-15.36 10.39-25.76 10.4-10.39 25.76-10.39h140q15.36 0 25.76 10.39 10.39 10.4 10.39 25.76V-200H720v-353.85q0-3.07-1.35-5.57-1.34-2.5-3.65-4.43L487.31-735q-3.08-2.69-7.31-2.69-4.23 0-7.31 2.69L245-563.85q-2.31 1.93-3.65 4.43-1.35 2.5-1.35 5.57V-200Zm-60 0v-353.85q0-17.17 7.68-32.53 7.69-15.37 21.24-25.31l227.7-171.54q18.95-14.46 43.32-14.46t43.44 14.46l227.7 171.54q13.55 9.94 21.24 25.31 7.68 15.36 7.68 32.53V-200q0 24.54-17.73 42.27Q744.54-140 720-140H562.31q-15.37 0-25.76-10.4-10.4-10.39-10.4-25.76v-201.53h-92.3v201.53q0 15.37-10.4 25.76-10.39 10.4-25.76 10.4H240q-24.54 0-42.27-17.73Q180-175.46 180-200Zm300-269.23Z"></path>
    </symbol>

    <symbol fill="currentcolor" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" id="icon_bar_chart">
        <path d="M676.15-180q-15.36 0-25.76-10.4Q640-200.79 640-216.16V-380q0-15.36 10.39-25.76 10.4-10.39 25.76-10.39h67.69q15.37 0 25.76 10.39Q780-395.36 780-380v163.84q0 15.37-10.4 25.76-10.39 10.4-25.76 10.4h-67.69Zm-230 0q-15.36 0-25.76-10.4Q410-200.79 410-216.16v-527.68q0-15.37 10.39-25.76 10.4-10.4 25.76-10.4h67.7q15.36 0 25.76 10.4Q550-759.21 550-743.84v527.68q0 15.37-10.39 25.76-10.4 10.4-25.76 10.4h-67.7Zm-229.99 0q-15.37 0-25.76-10.4-10.4-10.39-10.4-25.76v-331.35q0-15.64 10.4-25.99 10.39-10.34 25.76-10.34h67.69q15.36 0 25.76 10.39Q320-563.06 320-547.69v331.35q0 15.65-10.39 25.99Q299.21-180 283.85-180h-67.69Z"></path>
    </symbol>
    <symbol fill="currentcolor" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" id="icon_shopping_bag">
        <path d="M252.31-100Q222-100 201-121q-21-21-21-51.31v-455.38Q180-658 201-679q21-21 51.31-21H330v-10q0-62.15 43.92-106.08Q417.85-860 480-860t106.08 43.92Q630-772.15 630-710v10h77.69Q738-700 759-679q21 21 21 51.31v455.38Q780-142 759-121q-21 21-51.31 21H252.31Zm0-60h455.38q4.62 0 8.46-3.85 3.85-3.84 3.85-8.46v-455.38q0-4.62-3.85-8.46-3.84-3.85-8.46-3.85H630v90q0 12.77-8.62 21.38Q612.77-520 600-520t-21.38-8.62Q570-537.23 570-550v-90H390v90q0 12.77-8.62 21.38Q372.77-520 360-520t-21.38-8.62Q330-537.23 330-550v-90h-77.69q-4.62 0-8.46 3.85-3.85 3.84-3.85 8.46v455.38q0 4.62 3.85 8.46 3.84 3.85 8.46 3.85ZM390-700h180v-10q0-37.61-26.19-63.81Q517.62-800 480-800q-37.62 0-63.81 26.19Q390-747.61 390-710v10ZM240-160v-480 480Z"></path>
    </symbol>
    <symbol fill="currentcolor" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" id="icon_stack">
        <path d="M480-421.77q-8.85 0-17.19-2.31-8.35-2.31-16.58-6.54L119.77-604.23q-9.85-5.62-14.15-13.85-4.31-8.23-4.31-18.07 0-9.85 4.31-18.08 4.3-8.23 14.15-13.85l326.46-173.61q8.23-4.23 16.58-6.54 8.34-2.31 17.19-2.31 8.85 0 17.19 2.31 8.35 2.31 16.58 6.54l326.84 173.61q9.85 5.62 14.16 13.85 4.31 8.23 4.31 18.08 0 9.84-4.31 18.07t-14.16 13.85L513.77-430.62q-8.23 4.23-16.58 6.54-8.34 2.31-17.19 2.31Zm0-58.84 294.92-155.54L480-791.69 185.46-636.15 480-480.61Zm.38-155.54ZM480-324.46l320.15-169.46q2.39-1.39 16.31-2.69 12 .76 19.65 9 7.66 8.23 7.66 20.23 0 8.3-3.66 14.99-3.65 6.7-11.96 11.16L513.77-274.46q-8.23 4.23-16.58 6.54-8.34 2.3-17.19 2.3-8.85 0-17.19-2.3-8.35-2.31-16.58-6.54l-314-166.77q-8.31-4.46-12.15-11.16-3.85-6.69-3.85-14.99 0-12 7.85-20.23 7.84-8.24 19.84-9 4.23-.77 8.16-.04 3.92.73 8.15 2.73L480-324.46Zm0 156.15 320.15-169.46q2.39-1.38 16.31-2.69 12 .77 19.65 9 7.66 8.23 7.66 20.23 0 8.31-3.66 15-3.65 6.69-11.96 11.15L513.77-118.31q-8.23 4.23-16.58 6.54-8.34 2.31-17.19 2.31-8.85 0-17.19-2.31-8.35-2.31-16.58-6.54l-314-166.77q-8.31-4.46-12.15-11.15-3.85-6.69-3.85-15 0-12 7.85-20.23 7.84-8.23 19.84-9 4.23-.77 8.16-.04 3.92.73 8.15 2.73L480-168.31Z"></path>
    </symbol>

</svg>



then create a common function to get icons and append current timestamp as query parameter. this function accept two arguments, first argument is icon id without prefix and second argument is comma separated custom classes if you want to give it to any icon. example in php:


public function icon ($icon_id, $classes = '') {
        return '<svg class="icon icon_'.$icon_id.' '.$classes.'"><use xlink:href="view/image/icon.svg?v='.time().'#icon_'.$icon_id.'"></use></svg>';
    }



then whenever you want to use any icon, just use that common function. for example:


echo icon('home');
echo icon('shopping_bag', 'custom_class_1, custom_class_2');



later remove that query parameter on live server or better put a fixed query parameter every time you add/update icons in icon.svg
if you have any suggestion or a better solution, please post. thanks
